# Handle POST/GET forms with Django and Bootstrap Modal

Tags: python, django, post, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I'm using different `forms` (`POST` and `GET`) in my `Django` web application and `Bootstrap modal` to do that.

In my template, user can choose some documents, submit the list of documents which is picked up to a Django form (`CustomerForm`) in my modal. This CustomerForm lets to send an email with user informations previously filled.

My CustomerForm looks like this :

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].empty_label = _('Select a country')
        self.fields['country'].queryset = self.fields['country'].queryset.order_by('name')
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
        self.fields['country'].required = True
        self.fields['institution'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', 'institution']
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('name@example.com')}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('First Name')}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Last Name')}),
            'institution': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Agency, company, academic or other affiliation')}),
        }
```

I have views.py file :

```
class HomeView(CreateView, FormView):
    """ Render the home page """

    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        # display some things 
        # ...

        if "DocumentSelected" in self.request.GET:
            checkbox_list = self.request.GET.getlist('DocumentChoice')
            document = Document.objects.filter(id__in=checkbox_list)
            kwargs['selected_document'] = document

        return super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        country = form.cleaned_data['country']

        for checkbox in self.request.GET.getlist('DocumentChoice'):
            document = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)
            token = self.gen_token(email)

            now = timezone.now()
            expiration = now + settings.DOWNLOAD_VALIDITY
            Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, doc_id=checkbox, token=token,
                                    expiration_date=expiration)

            self.send_email(email, document.upload, document.publication.title, token)

        return super(HomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And finally in my HTML template you can find something which looks like this :

```
<form method="GET" action="">

    <!-- Table with checkboxes - User has to check wanted objects -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="DocumentSelected" value="{% trans 'Save document(s)' %}"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="{% trans 'Send document(s)' %}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form> 

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">{% trans 'Your informations' %}</h4>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="" novalidate>
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.country|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{ form.institution|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{% trans 'Your cart' %}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="model-body">
            {% for element in selected_document|dictsort:'format' %}
              <!-- Display wanted objects -->
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="{% trans 'Send' %}"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Process :**

This is the needed way :

- User has to check one or multiple documents
- User submits the choice and a modal containing CustomerForm is opening.
- User fills CustomerForm fields and see in `Cart part` his document(s)
- User submits the CustomerForm and an email is sent with previous informations/documents.

I think my method could work, but I don't overcome to call `form_valid` function and I would like to write correctly this class.

There is certainly ugly issues and I apologize by advance. But this is not the best way to improve myself and doesn't reproduce these issues ? ;)

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

I made something which seems to work. I removed `data-dismiss="modal"` from my modal submit button. I read that this attribute closed my modal and didn't post any form !
Finally, is it a good way to do what I did ?

Is it possible to replace both buttons `Save documents` and `Send documents` by an unique button which get documents and open the modal ?

Answer (score 1):

I made something which seems to work. I removed data-dismiss="modal" from my modal submit button.

Previously :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="{% trans 'Send' %}"/>
```

Now :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="{% trans 'Send' %}"/>
```

It works now !
It was because `data-dismiss="modal"` closed the modal and I didn't know that.